# How to logging output in console to file?

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, java.util.logging

The NetBeans generate code like `Logger.getLogger(svr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` to output exception in catch.It will display in console.
After I deploy my project,I cannot see any exception info.How to output those error messages to file and in console when console is available?

Thanks folks.

Comment: @David Grant Sorry I did't said that...Yes `java.util.logging.Logger`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logging system in NetBeans is based on the standard JDK's java.util.logging and complies to it as much as possible. In order to output error messages to a file, you can provide your own logging properties file on the classpath of your project.

See the following links for more info :

- Netbeans logging :
  http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/doc-files/logging.html
- Java Util logging with logging properties file sample :
  http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143

Comment: Thank you.But in my case, NetBeans uses `Logger.getLogger(svr.class.getName())`,which I have to set for each logger. Is is essential to use a single logger instead?

Comment: You can configure logging on a global level. Package specific Loggers and Handlers may override this level. See the comments in the logging properties of the second link for more info.