# Can I configure Netbeans 7 to send all of the Console output to a file?

Tags: java, log4j, netbeans-7

I'm working with a code base containing over 2500 System.out.println statements. Besides refactoring, is there a way to get them all to send their output to a file? I'm running it using Netbeans 7. Log4j is incorporated into the project, but only a few hundred Logger methods are used within the project.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882868/how-to-logging-output-in-console-to-file

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I'm trying to direct ALL of the output generated by `System.out.println` calls to a file.

Comment: are you developing any netbeans plugin (or) you want your web app specific System.out to a file?

Comment: @thinksteep I've been trying to debug a bioinformatics pipeline that, for now anyway, is being run from within Netbeans. I wanted to capture everything going through System.out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact your code base uses log4j is rather irrelevant, since the `System.out.println` calls you want to redirect bypass the whole logging framework.

My first suggestion would be to replace the `System.out.println` calls by a log statement. A find-and-replace should almost allow you to do this.

Otherwise, you can just set another `PrintStream` as `System.out` using [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29). Example of this can be found [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and) and [here](http://another-lazy-blogger.blogspot.com/2008/04/did-you-ever-got-frustrated-with.html)

Comment: Last link was exactly what I needed. Basically: `File file = new File("/home/username/filename.log"); PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); System.setOut(printStream);`